# GCM client not receiving messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My GCM client is not receiving any type of notification. I am able to register the token on the backend. I have double checked my Sender id & the api key which i have got by registering on the google api's. The client never receives any GCM message. I am unable to figure out the core reason behind it

```
public class MessageListener extends GcmListenerService {

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param from SenderID of the sender.
 * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
 *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    super.onMessageReceived(from, data);
    Log.d("AGCM", "Message from ::" + from + " Bundle ::" + data.toString());
}}
```

Manifest :

```
<application
    android:name=".AGCMApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".GCMInitializationService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <!-- Meta data required for Google Play Services -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!-- GCM components start -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.agcm.MessageListener"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name="com.example.agcm.gcm.InstanceIDChangeListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.agcm.gcm.GCMIntentService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.agcm.gcmdownload.GCMAppInstallReceiver"></receiver>
    <!-- GCM components end -->
</application>
```

Getting token snippet :

```
if (GCMUtils.checkGooglePlaySevices(getApplicationContext(), mRegistrationCallbacks)) {
                    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(context);
                    registrationToken = instanceID.getToken(senderID,
                            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend(registrationToken, context,urlToHit,appPackage);
                }
```

Message listener is never getting invoked.

Comment: Do you received any error code? can you provide us the logs? For the meantime, please read the offical GCM documentation: (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved, it appears based on your manifest that we have a pretty similar setup and suffering from the same symptoms.